# Jquery mobile - Android browser

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have developed a jquery mobile application for my site http://tastykhana.in/m there is an issue when the application is opened in the Android default web-kit browser.

I have to zoom in to view the UI correctly as it does not fit the screen and the fonts, input are very small.

What am i doing wrong here, as the site works well in the opera mini browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be something with the page's CSS, have you tried using something like

```
content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;
```

Here is a simple tutorial:
http://www.engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/2008/06/19/tutorial-building-a-website-for-the-iphone/